# Powershell Get-Date altered to another zone

Tags: date, powershell, datetime, date-conversion

I'm constructing a script to read dates from files, and I've been getting a strange problem after reading the EXIF ***'Date Taken'*** data.

The ultimate purpose is to rename directories of images using the EXIF date.

***So, the problem:***

I have a variable in DateTime format:

```
PS > $oldtime
25 May 2015 16:44:07
```

I convert the date using **Get-Date** to another format:

```
$newtime = $oldTime | Get-Date -Format yyyyMMdd_hhmmss
```

I get this output:

```
PS > $newtime
20150525_044407
```

I am assuming that the date is being altered to cater for Time Zone or something, but I am confused why, as I am trying to specify and extract the date.

What I was expecting is:

```
PS > $newtime
20150525_164407
```

Does anyone know how to get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your date format string, use `HH` for 24-hour time. `hh` gives you 12-hour (AM/PM).

```
$oldTime | Get-Date -Format yyyyMMdd_HHmmss;
```

Comment: Unbelievable I missed this. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ Thanks a lot.